# Why won't data get passed from one component to the next?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to pass the `this.prompt()` from `TitleBar` to `Portfolio`.  Am I doing it the right way?

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
var TitleBar = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return(
     <div className="jumbotron">
      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">name name</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.prompt} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>
      </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));

var Portfolio = React.createClass({

  this.props.prompt(
    alert("hi");
  );

  render: function() {
    return(
      <p className="text-primary">Portfolio</p>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Portfolio prompt={this.prompt}/>, document.getElementById('portfolio'));
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
var TitleBar = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return(
     <div className="jumbotron">
      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">name name</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.prompt} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>
      </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));

var Portfolio = React.createClass({

  this.props.prompt(
    alert("hi");
  );

  render: function() {
    return(
      <p className="text-primary">Portfolio</p>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Portfolio prompt={this.prompt}/>, document.getElementById('portfolio'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `export body;` at the end of your `body.js` and `import { body } from "./relativePathTo-body.js"` at the top of `index.js`.

Side note: if you want to use `body.prompt` in both files, break that code into another file and export it. Then import it into both `index.js` and `body.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Babel as the transpiler you must explicitly export and import the module or object:

```
// in the export file
var Body = //..

// at the bottom of the file using a named export
export Body
//-------------------------------

// in the import file
import { Body } from './path/to/body.js'
```

or

```
// in the export file
var Body = //..

// at the bottom of the file using a default export
export default Body
//-------------------------------

// in the import file
import Body from './path/to/body.js'
```

It's also import to know that this syntax only works if you're using a transpiler like Babel. If you didn't you'd be forced to use another module system like CommonJS: `module.exports = Body` to export and `var Body = require('./path/to/body.js')` to import.

Read more about the many other use cases of [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) at developer.mozilla.org.

Comment: I just posted my edit, why's my page going blank all of a sudden?

Comment: I like your way, the first one in particular.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, I don't see in both files you're using the other. And on the imports- they can be relative to the file, it doesn't have to be absolute. So if one file is next to another you can just do `'./file.js'`. Search 'relative path' on this [page](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) for more information.

Comment: Also, typically in React there is only one JS script used. So there will be a single `ReactDOM.render(<Body />, document.getElementById('body'));` statement. I've never used more than one so I don't know what kind of issues you'd experience. One thing for sure is that the order of the scripts play a role in dependencies with imports/exports.

Comment: Yeah one JS script is normally used.  I just wanted to try 2 of em out just to experiment.

Comment: Where in `body.js` are you using `index`? There seems no use of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134023/discussion-between-keitha-and-chompy).